# How do we use the latest OpenCV precompiled library for codeblocks 20 with mingw64 compiler?

Tags: opencv, c++11, codeblocks

I was trying to use OpenCV for a certain project, and I'm used to codeblocks, so I use the codeblocks IDE for all my C and C++ programming. I did try to link the libraries, but I still have this bunch of errors.

Comment: there are no precompiled opencv libs for mingw, you must build those from github src first

Comment: After several hours i finally made it to work it turns out that my compiler was the TDM x64 and not the mingw64. After i did that the program works fine.  The link for the precompiled libraries are here : https://github.com/huihut/OpenCV-MinGW-Build/